# Xcode 7.1 crashes when exporting for Ad hoc deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, export, xcode7, adhoc

Xcode crashes after "archive".

Click on "export", then select "save for ad hoc deployment". It will crash trying to create the .ipa file.

I've tried the suggested answer for xcode 6 which is to close the project and only leave the organizer open. This does not work for xcode 7.

I've had to co-install xcode 6.4 on my machine, and the xport does work.

Anyone having the same issue or knows a fix?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unchecked "Include Bytecode" and it worked. Bytecode seems to be necessary only for iTunes deployment.